# How to package a Ruby application?

Tags: ruby, qt4, packaging

I've got an application in Ruby that uses the Qt 4 bindings. I want to be able to package and release it.

I've looked at other applications such as rake and puppet to see how they're packaged. Both rake and puppet are packaged as gems. I started going down this route when I realized that both rake and puppet are more system level tools rather than user-level applications.

I also looked at orca, but it's windows only.

Are there other options available for packaging a Ruby GUI app other than gem or orca? I'd like something that's cross platform.

Comment: what platform are you packaging for?

Comment: cross-platform ideally. I've updated the question to reflect that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [platform](http://guides.rubygems.org/specification-reference/#platform=) specification for gems. You can package up a gem for each platform that your code supports.

> Some gems consist of pre-compiled code (“binary gems”). It’s especially important that they set the platform attribute appropriately.

Comment: Would I still need to do something like this if a gem I require as a dependency has pre-compiled code or is the gem I require supposed to take care of this?

Comment: The required gem should take care of that for you.